# Find error: highlight side menu based on page scrolling position

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to highlight side menu based on page scrolling position. The nice example is shown [here](http://jsfiddle.net/vu6hN/732/).

However, when practising in a different way, not able to get similar effect for scrolling. Codes are [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wx2dLpe5/6/).

```js
$('#sn').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.target').each(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).position().top) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#sn a').removeClass('active');
            $('#sn a[href=#'+ id +']').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
#sn {
    width: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    }
#sn a {
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* Change the link color on hover */
#sn a:hover {
    background-color: #555;
    color: white;
}

#sn .active {
    background-color: #666;
    color: rgb(58, 133, 204);
}
#sn .active:hover {
    background-color: #4f5f;
    color: rgb(235, 157, 13);
}

section {
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="sn" class="toggle_sn">
  <a href="#abt_sec" class="item active">About</a>
  <a href="#edu_sec" class="item">Education</a>
  <a href="#soc_sec" class="item">Social</a>
</ul>

<section class="target" id="abt_sec">
  ABOUT
</section>

<section class="target" id="edu_sec">
  EDUCATION
</section>

<section class="target" id="soc_sec">
  SOCIAL
</section>
```

What I'm doing wrong? How to debug errors in web designing? Is this jquery version problem (e.g. is in 1.10.1, mine is 3.3.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Add class="target" to your sections. Like so:

```
<section id="abt_sec" class="target">ABOUT</section>
<section id="edu_sec" class="target">EDUCATION</section>
<section id="soc_sec" class="target">SOCIAL</section>
```

Because jQuery code selects elements with `target` class `$('.target').each(function()`

2) Correct last line syntax:

From this:

```
$('#sn a[href=#'+ id +']').addClass('active');
```

to this:

```
$('#sn a[href="#'+ id +'"]').addClass('active');
```

Because css selector should be in this syntax: `#sn a[href="#abt_sec"]` instead of: `#sn a[href=#abt_sec]`.
This doesn't work in your case because jQuery v3.3.1, if you change the jQuery version in the working example from jsFiddle from 1.1 to 3.3.1 that one doesn't work either with same error like your example:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #sn a[href=#abt_sec]

So your code should look like this:

```
$('#sn').on('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parent().find('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.target').each(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() >= $(this).position().top) {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#sn a').removeClass('active');
            $('#sn a[href="#'+ id +'"]').addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

A codepen to see it working: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/AugustinF/pen/zjZwGZ)

Comment: Thanks for this, but still not highlighting. [updated code](https://jsfiddle.net/wx2dLpe5/6/)

Comment: I see. But did not understand why (2nd point). Why it is working in the example code, but not for mine?